# Vertex Paint NOT based off geometry/ vertices?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-colors, vertex-paint, weight-paint-mode, vertex-paint-mode

I want to vertex paint on a model but when I want to paint a blank face, it does this:
[image]

I understand Vertex paint uses VERTICES, but where there are smooth faces (and lack of vertices) am I just SOL?

Comment: To give a nice, rounded answer, it would help to know which version of Blender you are using.. there have been some recent changes in the vertex-colour interface. The principle remains the same, though, if you want a boundary between colours not coincident with an edge, you should probably be painting into a UV-mapped texture.

Comment: I'm using Blender 3.1. So should I paint on the UV image itself and not the model?

Comment: Okydoky... 'Texture Paint' may be the mode you're looking for, in which you can paint on the model, or into the image,  into an image texture. Will get to it, if no one else does first.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of telling you what you know already..

'Vertex Colors' are stored in layers on the geometry, of (vertex-per-face) Face Corners. In 3.2+, they are looking to become 'Color Attributes', which could also be stored on vertices, shared by faces.

When you're **Vertex Painting**, you're storing color-data on those points. There is no more information than that available to shaders, which must linearly interpolate between the colours found on them. So, no, you can't paint half a face. Resolution is limited by the density of your geometry.

However, if you're **Texture Painting**, into a separately stored UV-mapped *image*, then shaders are interpolating between the UV *coordinates* found on the points, and can return the color found at the interpolated point in the image.

The texture-painting interface in Blender allows you to paint directly onto mapped geometry. It gives many options for defining brushes, their behaviour, masking.. etc. It's a little learning-curve all of its own. Typically you would set the object up with a material that expresses the image in one channel or another, and paint while watching the effect in Material Preview.

[image]

(Left, image.. Right, resulting material )